# How can cicle Temporary Table with cicle white in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that creates this temporary table in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE #TeporaryTableAcqua
(
    Data DateTime, 
    Nome NVarchar(100), 
    Valore Decimal(10,2)
)
```

In my stored procedure, I populate this temporary table with any record.

```
--RECUPERO L'ACQUA BEVUTA OGGI
INSERT INTO #TeporaryTableAcqua
   SELECT 
       'ACQUA BEVUTA', 
       CONVERT(varchar(12), data, 105),
       SUM(QUANTITA) * 100 
   FROM 
       OmniacareDataProduction.dbo.MV_Acqua A
   WHERE 
       CONVERT(varchar(12), data,105) = CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 105)
   GROUP BY 
       CONVERT(varchar(12), data, 105)
```

Now I want to create a cicle that select a row at time, so I have build this code but I get an error:

```
DECLARE @NROW INT

SELECT @NROW = COUNT(*) 
FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua 

DECLARE @Nome As NVARCHAR(100)

WHILE (@NROW>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @Nome = Nome 
    FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua 
    LIMIT 1

    EXEC [P_TF_UTILITY_Set_FileBodies]
         @FileTempID = @FileTempID, 
         @FieldID = 8, @Value = @Nome, @RowID = 2, @OrdinalID = 1

    DELETE FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua LIMIT 1

    SELECT @NROW = COUNT(*) 
    FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua 
END
```

The error is on the `LIMIT 1`.

How can I fixed it?

Comment: `LIMIT` is not a standard SQL command - it's a specific MySQL/Postgres extension, which is not available in SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the row there is a [`TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) Clause in sql server. There is no any `Limit` type of thing in sql server.

So, Here is your updated script.

```
DECLARE @NROW INT
SELECT @NROW=COUNT(*) FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua 

DECLARE @Nome As NVARCHAR(100)

WHILE (@NROW>0)
BEGIN
        Select TOP 1 @Nome=Nome From #TeporaryTableAcqua Order By Nome 

        EXEC [P_TF_UTILITY_Set_FileBodies] @FileTempID=@FileTempID, @FieldID=8, @Value=@Nome, @RowID = 2, @OrdinalID = 1         

        --DELETE TOP (1) FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua
        DELETE FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua
          WHERE Nome = @Nome

        SELECT @NROW=COUNT(*) FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua 
END
```

Comment: I have one error on Delete (TOP 1).... "Proper syntax in the vicinity of ' ( ' ."

Comment: Of course, with no `ORDER BY` clause used in *either* of the `SELECT` and the `DELETE`, there's *no guarantee* that the row that is deleted is the same row from which data was selected.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, why you speak this?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, you are right. I have to use `Order by` clause. Thanks for point me out.

Comment: @bircastri - because when you do `Select TOP 1 @Nome=Nome From #TeporaryTableAcqua` without an `ORDER BY` clause, there's no guarantee on *which* row from the table the data will be provided. Later, when you run `DELETE TOP (1) FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua`, there's *no* guarantee that the row that you delete will be the one that was previously used to set `@Nome`. You need to apply `ORDER BY` clauses to both of these statement, such that the order is unambiguous.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I have updated my answer... Thanks for point out.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember that when a query is executed its results are returned in a undefined order, unless specificly specified by an order by clause.

It is also important to consider what constitiutes a uniqueidentifier in each row of your data.

If Nome is unique then the piece of code below will work for you.

If not then you will have to use multiple fields in your order by clause and in the where clause of the delete statement.

```
DECLARE @Nome As NVARCHAR(100)

WHILE exists (select * from #TeporaryTableAcqua)

BEGIN

    Set @Nome = (Select TOP 1 Nome From #TeporaryTableAcqua Order by Nome asc)

    EXEC [P_TF_UTILITY_Set_FileBodies] @FileTempID=@FileTempID, @FieldID=8, @Value=@Nome, @RowID = 2, @OrdinalID = 1      

    DELETE FROM #TeporaryTableAcqua where Nome = @Nome

END
```